# Is there convincing evidence of a difference in the population averages?

Tags: statistics

My question is as follows:

> Auto Exhaust and Lead Concentration in Blood. Researchers took
>   independent random samples from two populations of police officers and
>   measured the level of lead concentration in their blood. The sample of
>   126 police officers subjected to constant inhalation of automobile
>   exhaust fumes in downtown Cairo had an average blood level
>   concentration of 29.2 μg/dl and an SD of 7.5 μg/dl; a control sample
>   of 50 police officers from the Cairo suburb of Abbasia, with no
>   history of exposure, had an average blood level concentration of 18.2
>   μg/dl and an SD of 5.8 μg/dl.
>   My work is as follows:

Given: 
Experimental:
n = 126
μ = 29.2
sd = 7.5

Control:
$n = 50$
$μ = 18.2$
$SD = 5.8$

Null hypothesis: $μ1 = μ2$

Alternative hypothesis: $μ1 ≠ μ2$

$$\left(\frac{(126-1)(7.5)^2 + (50-1)(5.8)^2}{(126+50-2)}\right)^{1/2}=7.06$$

$$SE = 7.06\sqrt{(1/ 126)+(1/50)} = 1.18$$

$$-11/(1.18)= -9.32$$

So this test statistic generates a very small P-value - meaning we can reject the null hypothesis?

Comment: Small $p$-values indicate evidence to reject hypothesis, depending on the tolerance of Type 1 errors.